# name 'MyAPI' is not defined while using Django rest_frameworkAPI

Tags: python, django

I am trying to deploy a ML model using Django rest framework, after setting up for approvals in the models.py for created project 'MyAPI' and setting up urls on both admin and of created project. And ran the bellow code.

```
C:\Users\Padmini\DjangoAPI>python manage.py runserver
```

got the following error

```
  File "C:\Users\Padmini\DjangoAPI\DjangoAPI\urls.py", line 21, in <module>
    path('api/', MyAPI.site.urls),
NameError: name 'MyAPI' is not defined
```

and my file arrangement as follows.
[there is DjangoAPI project folder and created app called 'MyAPI'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cJymG.png)

Comment: have you imported it ?

Comment: eg: import MyAPI

Comment: at top of urls file